# Sync (Federate) users between two Keycloak Servers via LDAP

Tags: ldap, keycloak, federated-identity

I have two keycloak servers running on Docker containers locally on my machine. One on port 8080 and the other one on 8888. What I am trying to do is to connect the one with port 8080 to the one with 8888. I want to do that because I want to federate users. This scenario should be a test for a much larger scenario where I want to connect multiple Keycloak servers to one main keycloak servers.

This main keycloak server should be the entry point for all authentication requests. I am currently trying to solve this problem by setting up User Federation on the main keycloak server (Port 8888) using ldap. The following picture shows my configuration:
[image: Keycloak LDAP Settings]

As you can see, when testing the connection url, it succeeds. However when trying to import users or even when clicking on "Test authentication", it just goes into an endless process which fails with "LDAP Query Failed". I suspect that something is wrong with the credentials (Users DN, Bind DN and Bind Credentials).

I did not found out how keycloak's ldap structure looks like, maybe some of you can help me configure this correctly. The Bind DN I tried is called "remote" (Bind Credentials is same as username), because I thought this must be the default admin account that is created when setting up Keycloak. Because the authentication fails, I suspect that this is not the right way to configure this whole scenario.

I hope I described the problem well and someone of you can help me out on this. Maybe you also have the correct page in the documentation for me to read about that?

Have a great day & Thank you kindly in advance!